# VueJS - How to handle multiple sets of checkboxes, rendered with v-for

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I have the following scenario. I get a list of `Questions` from my backend and each `Question` contains the following properties:

- Id
- Statement
- Choices[] (of type String).

Now, I'm rendering the questions with `v-for` and displaying them as a form with the `Statement` as a simple `<p>` and the `choices` are a set of checkboxes (rendered also with `v-for`).

```
Question Statement 1
[x] choice1
[] choice2
[x] choice3
--------------------
Question Statement 2
[x] choice1
[x] choice2
[] choice3
--------------------
Question Statement 3
[x] choice1
[] choice2
[] choice3
--------------------
```

I know how to bind a set of checkboxes to a given property, but here I don't have a single set of checkboxes, but multiple, depending on the number of questions fetched from the backend.
I want in the end to submit the form and send an HTTP POST request to the backend with the answers given (something like the following):

```
[
    {
        "questionId": 1,
        "selectedAnswers": [choice1, choice3]
    },
    {
        "questionId": 2,
        "selectedAnswers": [choice1, choice2]
    },
    {
        "questionId": 3,
        "selectedAnswers": [choice1]
    }
]
```

My problem is that I cannot find a way to bind all the selected choices. If I select and array and bind them in the `input` with `v-model` the last checkbox that I will select will override everything. I need to somehow bind the array of selected choices alongside the questionId so everything will unique.

Do you have any clues on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object from the items that come from your backend after fetching them:

```
// presuming the variable holding your backend data is called `data`

let questions = [...data]

for (let question of questions) {
    question['selectedChoices'] = []
}
```

Now render your questions with the questions array, and bind the checkboxes in each question to the `selectedChoices` array.

Comment: That fits perfectly with what I need! Thanks a lot, amirhshahbazi!